# How to make Intellij IDEA use parallel and gradle build cache for building

Tags: gradle, intellij-idea, gradle-cache

What controls how an Intellij IDEA IDE build / rebuild uses the gradle build cache and parallel options?

I have gradle build cache setup and if I run gradle via IDEA runConfiguration I see the following:

```
45s clean build --parallel -x test
34s build --parallel -x test
```

If I click on the hammer to build or select Build : rebuild, I see times of 2m10s and above.

## How I enabled the cache

On the commandline and via a runConfiguration, the speed increase is excellent.  When building via Intellij's hammer things are much slower

### gradle.properties

```
# Enable gradle build cache
org.gradle.caching=true
gradle.cache.push=false
```

### settings.gradle

```
ext.inJenkins = System.getenv().containsKey("BUILD_NUMBER")

buildCache {
  local {
    enabled = !inJenkins
  }
  remote(HttpBuildCache) {
      enabled = true
      url = "${artifactory_url}/gradlecache-generic-development-local/"
      ...
      push = inJenkins
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Probably you don't have parallelism enabled in gradle properties.

Add to gradle.properties

```
org.gradle.parallel=true
```

have a good day

Comment: Thanks.  Any idea why intellij isn't using the build cache properties when CLI does?  Also, I'm pretty sure that I only want parallel for the build and not test execution.

Comment: Please make sure to use same Gradle in command line and in IDE and have 'Gradle' set for the Settings (Preferences on macOS) | Build, Execution, Deployment | Build Tools | Gradle | 'Build and run using' option. Also invoke 'Build' action in IDE, not 'Rebuild'.